# How to set view weights?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I'm trying to get the views inside a LinearLayout to fill the width. I have tried setting it by using LayoutParams, but it gave me an error:

My code:

```
EditText et = new EditText(v.getContext());
                    et.setHint("asset ");
                    et.setTextSize(12);
                    et.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.25f));
                    et.setPadding(0, 15, 0, 10);
```

The error:

> The constructor ActionBar.LayoutParams(int, int, float) is undefined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just what the error says, no `ActionBarLayoutParams` constructor takes a float. You need one of the [available graivty constants](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity) for the gravity

But it looks like you are importing the wrong `LayoutParams`. If this is for a `LinearLayout` and not `ActionBar` then you need to be importing `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`

```
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams
```

[ActionBar.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.LayoutParams.html)

[LinearLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Answer (score 5):

change your import to use LinearLayout.LayoutParams not ActionBar.LayoutParams

or change code

```
et.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.25f));
```

to

```
et.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.25f));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `LinearLayout`, I guess you should call `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.